# How to write a software to sync files to ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, synchronization

I have this idea of writing an application to automatically sync files to a specific place for an ipad every time the ipad is plugged in the computer.
The problem is I've never developed a software like this before. Right now I have these two big questions:
- How to detect when an ipad is plugged in the computer?
- How to connect to and copy files over the ipad?

To make things clear, the application I want to develop should have similar functions like **iTools** (not **iTunes**).

Does anyone here have experiences in developing this kind of application? Would you please share with me how to start with this project, because I'm clueless :(

Comment: What on earth is iTools? As far as I know, iTunes is the one that does everything you describe.

Comment: To my knowledge, it would be impossible to create this kind of app on an iPad. iOS is a pretty closed system that restraint the developpers and users with local storage. Maybe you want to do this with Android tablets?

Comment: @Soader03: I would love to but customer asks for iPad and they have their reasons ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a rather simple option; use a internet based service to accomplish this task - just as DropBox, iCloud and similar services do it already. Maybe you can get a lot closer to your goals by simply connecting to the [API of DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers), [SugarSync](https://www.sugarsync.com/developer) or alike.

Using a direct (USB-) connection to the device will be rather tough to implement and, to my knowledge, will prevent you from selling the resulting software through Apple's channels. I am not saying that it was impossible (see [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)) but I am saying that such endeavor will involve a lot of reverse engineering of undocumented functions to a degree that might be considered illegal in certain countries. Additionally, maintaining such software will be very demanding as Apple frequently introduces changes within their communication protocol/s.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I knew it would be difficult because Apple's really strict on these kinds of permissions.
I'll try the API of DropBox as @Till mentioned.
Once again, thank you all!