# xcode to display iPad camera roll in OS X

Tags: macos, ipad, xcode4.5

I am trying to create an OSX application that, when my ipad is connected through USB, it will display the photos on my mac and allow for downloading them to a specific folder. Basically it is like an iPhoto clone but it syncs live everytime a photo is taken. I know how to do this on the iPad itself but I am not familiar with OSX programming. If anyone has any samples or can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't the OS X Image Capture app pretty much do this already?

Comment: Here's a related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095048/how-to-write-a-software-to-sync-files-to-ipad

Answer (score 0):

The [SimpleCameraBrowser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SimpleCameraBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code would be a good starting point. It uses the [ImageCaptureCore](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ImageCaptureServicesProgrammingGuide/CreatinganApplicationUsingImageCaptureCore/CreatinganApplicationUsingImageCaptureCore.html) framework to show a list of images on connected cameras and to download those images to a folder. iOS devices are recognized as cameras and it should work just fine with an iPad.

Comment: Hey thanks OMZ. I actually revised it a bit. My final question is how can I get it to print? I figured out the downloading but I wanted a button that allows me to print and I don't know what framework uses this. As of now, if I download the photo I can open the folder it's in then open the photo and print that way. I'm just looking to eliminate that step. Any thoughts? I'm stumped

Comment: Printing is a completely different topic, please ask a new question about that or maybe [do some reading in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Printing/osxp_aboutprinting/osxp_aboutprt.html).